# Net beans binding

Tags: java, netbeans

I am learning java and I am using Netbeans IDE.
Netbeans interface provides the option to Bind a component's property to another component's property. For example you can set a Jbutton's "enabled" property to be bount to another component's enabled property. This way, when a button (jbutton1) become not enabled you can set the other button (jbutton2) to become not enabled too, without having to use a

```
 jbutton2.setEnabled(false)
```

statement for the second button. Using

```
 jbutton1.setEnabled(false)
```

is enough. The other button (jbutton2) that is bound becomes disabled too.

My 1st question is, is the whole binding usage in cases like the above recommended? Are there any possible problems with using Binding of component's properties?

My 2nd question is, can a component's property be set to bind to a variable? For example I may have 15 buttons that have to be disabled when a boolean variable named "usercanpressbuttons" has "false" value. Can this be done?

3rd question is, can this kind of binding be done by coding, instead of using the netbeans interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.-You can. I've done it. But I wouldn't recommend it. It's easy to lose track of the binded values, because you can't see them in the editor. If anybody else needs to check, update or correct the form, there's a good chance he/she wouldn't notice the binding. Finally, last time I used it, sometimes the binding just stopped working. Maybe was something else in my code, but I wasn't able to pinpoint the cause.

2-yes, you can. In fact that is the most appealing use of binding; you can bind every control in the form with a variable/object member/etc. and display it. But

3-If you want to that by coding, it's better to use a listener and a custom method. That will give you full control over the events. Just make a method to disable the buttons, like:

```
public void setButtons(boolean value){
button.setEnabled(value);
button1.setEnabled(value);
button2.setEnabled(value);
button3.setEnabled(value);
}
```

and call it when setting the usercanpressbuttons variable.

Comment: Thanks. About question3: I understand that I can do it by using methods like you say. But can we actually program by code Binding? Or binding controls is an only-Netbeans thing, outside standard java?

Comment: As a concept, it's implemented within several tools. The one in netbeans is know as JSR 295. Eclipse provides support for it too, and certainly we can use binding. But the the code generated with the matisse editor (netbeans' gui designer) is a ”netbeans” thing.